# Synchronization/Replication of MySQL database on XAMPP with most of time offline laptop and online desktop

Tags: mysql, synchronization, xampp

**My case:**

- one laptop with XAMPP and I like to work outside without internet connection to not be distracted for increased productivity
- one desktop with XAMPP which is always connected
- htdocs folder is synchronized with Dropbox - this works great

**What I want to achieve:**

To have some kind of automatic synchronization/replication of mysql database across these two devices and when I work on laptop offline and I came online I want to all changes in MySQL on my laptop to be replicated to MySQL database on my desktop

**Solutions which I tried:**

- use central MySQL server to which I could connect from both of them - this is very good and easy solution, but I couldn't work offline without internet connection on my laptop
- I was using dropbox for synchronization of mysql data folder - many of users are saying that it works flawlessly, but I ended with corrupted data

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SymmetricDS can synchronize MySQL databases in an environment with expected network disconnects.

A free headless version can be found at symmetricds.org.